# Неправильно изменяет размер как сделать правильно

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Нужно помещать в RelativeLayout Картинку, но она большая, и андроид не правильно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]задаёт размер картинки

Comment: разметку покажите

Comment: для более точного решения нужна разметка, но для начала попробуйте выставить match_parent по высоте.

Comment: в xml задай параметр android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии Вообщем android:scaleType="centerCrop" подойдёт